# JointState message publishes different angle and velocity

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

I am running gazebo simulations with Robotis' OpenMANIPULATOR-P. (https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/openmanipulator_p/overview/)

I am using ros melodic with UBUNTU 18.04, but using kinetic-devel of OpenMANIPULATOR package because when I tried to run simulations with melodic-devel, the robot was dismantled as soon as I started the simulation.

Anyway, during the simulation, I subscribed 'JointState' message to get the data of the robot's joint angles and velocities during the simulation.

[image]

The picture above shows the graphs of the actual joint angles that are subscribed from 'JointState' in blue line, and the desired joint angles in red line. Those two lines are almost identical and hard to find the difference between them.

[image]

The second picture shows the graphs of the actual joint velocities that are subscribed from 'JointState' in blue line, the desired joint velocities in red line, and the numerical derivative of actual joint angles in the first picture with respect to time in yellow line. As you can see, the joint velocities subscribed from 'JointState' message does not matches with the joint angles subscribed from the same message. Using kinetic-devel in melodic version made this difference? Or should I do some data processing procedure for joint velocities? I leave part of my code for subscribing 'JointState'.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import tf
import csv
import copy
import time
import numpy as np
from math import cos as cos
from math import sin as sin
from math import sqrt as sqrt
from math import pi as pi
from math import atan2 as atan2
from cmath import cos as ccos
from cmath import sin as csin
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectory, JointTrajectoryPoint
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from controller_manager_msgs.srv import SwitchController, SwitchControllerRequest

global mat
mat = np.matrix

def joint_state_callback(msg):
    global q, dq, eff
    q = mat(msg.position)
    dq = mat(msg.velocity)
    eff = mat(msg.effort)

def main():
    rospy.init_node('OPro_example')
    global q, dq, eff

    q = np.empty(shape=(1,6))
    dq = np.empty(shape=(1,6))
    eff = np.empty(shape=(1,6))

    rospy.Subscriber('/joint_states', JointState, joint_state_callback)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit:

I modified the part of the code for subscribing to parse `name` properly of the `JointState` message, but this didn't fix the problem.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import tf
import csv
import copy
import time
import numpy as np
from math import cos as cos
from math import sin as sin
from math import sqrt as sqrt
from math import pi as pi
from math import atan2 as atan2
from cmath import cos as ccos
from cmath import sin as csin
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectory, JointTrajectoryPoint
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from controller_manager_msgs.srv import SwitchController, SwitchControllerRequest

global mat
mat = np.matrix

def joint_state_callback(msg):
    global q, dq, eff, name
    valid_joint_names = ['joint1', 'joint2', 'joint3', 'joint4', 'joint5', 'joint6']
    position = []
    velocity = []
    effort = []
    jname = []
    for joint_name in valid_joint_names:
        if joint_name in msg.name:
            idx = msg.name.index(joint_name)
            jname.append(msg.name[idx])
            effort.append(msg.effort[idx])
            position.append(msg.position[idx])
            velocity.append(msg.velocity[idx])
    if set(jname) == set(valid_joint_names):
        name = mat(jname)
        q = mat(position)
        dq = mat(velocity)
        eff = mat(effort)

def main():
    rospy.init_node('OPro_example')
    global q, dq, eff

    q = np.empty(shape=(1,6))
    dq = np.empty(shape=(1,6))
    eff = np.empty(shape=(1,6))

    rospy.Subscriber('/joint_states', JointState, joint_state_callback)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

2nd Edit:

I solved the problem aforementioned. When I reduced the step size, 'JointState' message published right velocities.

[image]

The picture above shows the graphs of the actual joint velocities that are subscribed from 'JointState' in red line, the desired joint velocities in green line when the step size is 20 ms. As you can see, the joint velocities subscribed from 'JointState' message show great difference with the desired values.

However, when the step size is set to 10 ms, the velocities subscribed from 'JointState' message is similar with the desired values.

If the step size is smaller than 10 ms, The subscribed velocities are similar with the desired ones. So, I ask another question. Does the step size affects the accuracy of subscribed message, similar by setting sampling frequency bigger or smaller than Nyquist frequency?

I used `effort_controllers/JointPositionController`, and I set up Ubuntu with real-time kernel when I tried to use Universal Robots before. Could the real-time kernel made this phenomenon?

3rd Edit:

I modified `max_step_size` to 0.0001, but the result didn't changed.

[image]

The picture above shows the graphs of the actual joint velocities that are subscribed from 'JointState' in red line, the desired joint velocities in green line when the step size is 20 ms. The red line became less noisy than before, but still incorrect.

I changed `empty.world` of OpenMANIPULATOR-P's kinematic-devel package. I leave the content of `.launch` file below.

```
<launch>
  <!-- These are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="paused" default="true"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="with_gripper" default="false"/>

  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find open_manipulator_p_gazebo)/worlds/empty.world"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
<arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Load the URDF into the ROS Parameter Server -->
  <include file="$(find open_manipulator_p_description)/launch/open_manipulator_p_upload.launch">
<arg name="with_gripper" value="$(arg with_gripper)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Run a python script to the send a service call to gazebo_ros to spawn a URDF robot -->
  <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
    args="-urdf -model robot -z 0.0 -param robot_description"/>

  <!-- Run controller utils -->
  <include file="$(find open_manipulator_p_gazebo)/launch/controller_utils.launch"/>

  <!-- ros_control robotis manipulator launch file -->
  <include file="$(find open_manipulator_p_gazebo)/launch/open_manipulator_p_controller.launch">
<arg name="with_gripper" value="$(arg with_gripper)"/>
  </include>
</launch>
```

4th Edit:

I also doubt that effort of `JointState` message is correct. I moved the 6th joint only, which one is the closest joint to the end-effector, by setting all the other joint's desired joint trajectory to 0. I generated 7th polynomial trajectory for the joint, and the picture below shows the desired angular acceleration.

[image]

If I move the joint with the desired trajectory, by $\tau=I\alpha$, the shape of the effort should resemble with the acceleration trajectory.

However, as you can see the picture below, the shape of the effort is different with the acceleration's shape.

[image]

The effort's shape is similar to $q-q_d$, where $q$ is angle from the `JointState` and $q_d$ is the desired angle.

[image]

It is understandable because I use PD controller to control the joint, so the shape of the effort is similar to the angle's difference. However, their shape should resemble with the shape of the angular acceleration because I move only one joint. Can I trust the effort data from `JointState`? If I made a mistake, how can I fix that?

※ I had to remove some of links and plots because I can't post more than 8 links.

Comment: Please edit your post to tell us 1) what type of joint controller you are using (e.g. `effort_controllers/JointPositionController`), and 2) in gazebo, what is your `max_step_size` ?

Comment: 3) Also show us your roslaunch command line.

Comment: @Mike973 I edited my post as you requested, but for 3), do you mean how I launch the simulater in the terminal? ```roslaunch open_manipulator_p_gazebo open_manipulator_p_gazebo.launch``` after I sourced ```setup.bash```.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to parse the `name` property of the `JointState` message.
That will tell you, for every index of the `position`, `velocity`, and `effort` arrays, which joint it refers to.
Please refer to the `JointState` documentation [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html#:%7E:text=%23%C2%A0All%C2%A0arrays%C2%A0in%C2%A0this%C2%A0message%C2%A0should%C2%A0have%C2%A0the%C2%A0same%C2%A0size%2C%C2%A0or%C2%A0be%C2%A0empty.%0A%23%C2%A0This%C2%A0is%C2%A0the%C2%A0only%C2%A0way%C2%A0to%C2%A0uniquely%C2%A0associate%C2%A0the%C2%A0joint%C2%A0name%C2%A0with%C2%A0the%C2%A0correct%0A%23%C2%A0states.).

Answer (score 0):

The results you are seeing is because your simulation is too crude i.e inaccurate.

Gazebo is a physics simulator: it models mass & friction & forces & acceleration. The Gazebo parameter `max_step_size` controls how often these physics calculations are made. On a modern computer, you want this parameter to be 1 millisecond or smaller. A smaller value should give more accurate output, but also may slow the simulation down.

Update: a JointPositionController ignores any joint-rotation velocity you provide. Use a JointVelocityController if you want that, and make sure you provide both position and velocity for each JointTrajectoryPoint.

Comment: I'm so sorry for reversing my thanks because of my confusion, but your answer didn't solved my problem. I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll try your advice later. And I updated my post because I have another question